# Error: operator'===' cannot be applied to '3.1415' y '1.4142'

Tags: typescript

I'm learning typescript and some functional programing and i found a message that i couldn't understand

```
const esperaN = (n) => {
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        const resultado = 3.1415;
        if (resultado === 1.4142) {
            reject("hubo un error");
        }
        setTimeout( () => accept(resultado), n);
    })
}
```

`Error: operator'===' cannot be applied to '3.1415' y '1.4142'.`

The same happens with `==`

Answer (score 2):

> El operador '===' no se puede aplicar a los tipos '3.1415' y '1.4142'.

Because TypeScript can see that `resultado` will *always* be 3.1415:

```
    const resultado = 3.1415;
    if (resultado === 1.4142) {
```

## Fix

Simplify your code to its equivalent:

```
const esperaN = (n) => {
    return Promise.reject("hubo un error");
}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I think this is *actually* a bug with TypeScript's literals. You cannot compare literals of different types, and TypeScript is treating those values as literals... of different types. If you replace one of those constants with the other, the expression does not produce this error - presumably because they are the same type.

Comment: Additionally, if you were to use a variable instead of a constant (even if the statements occur one after the other), the expression compiles just fine. So it isn't so much that TypeScript can see that `resultado` will always be `3.1414` so much as it is that TypeScript mistakes the constants for different types entirely, and there is no equality operator with a signature capable of supporting those two types.